# Fine-tune zero-shot classification model multi-label

Tags: nlp, multilabel-classification, text-classification, finetuning, zero-shot-learning

I started a small project where I am trying to fine-tune a zero-shot classification model on a proprietary dataset. I was thinking to use the NLI approach, building contradiction and entailment statements for each of my sentences/labels pairs.

I have a dataset with sentences and for each of them multiple true labels.

However, I am not sure on what is the best way to approach this, given that in literature I have only seen the case where there is only one label per sentence.

Making one example:

Sentence 1. Classes = ['A','B','C']

Should I build my dataset generating three different samples

Sentence 1. This is about 'A' + Entailment label
Sentence 1. This is about 'B' + Entailment label
Sentence 1. This is about 'C' + Entailment label

or generating only one as follows:

Sentence 1. This is about A, B, C. + Entailment label

I am happy to hear any other ideas on this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NLI approach. The NLI task requires the model to identify the relationship between two sentences: a hypothesis and a premise. The relationship can be entailment, contradiction, or neutral, depending on the compatibility of the premise and hypothesis.

Both approaches you mentioned have their own advantages and disadvantages.

**Multiple Samples Approach:**

Advantages:

- Provides distinct training instances for each label, allowing the model to learn specific relationships between the sentence and individual labels.

Disadvantages:

- Data Redundancy: Generating multiple samples for the same sentence may lead to redundancy in the training data, potentially increasing the computational resources required for training without significant additional information gain
- Increased Training Time: The duplication of sentences for each label can lead to longer training times, especially for large datasets, as the model needs to process and learn from each duplicated sample.
- Potential Overfitting: The model may be more prone to overfitting on the training data due to the increased number of similar samples, which could impact its generalization to unseen data.

**Single Sample Approach:**

Advantages:

- Reduces data redundancy and training time by consolidating multiple labels into a single sample, potentially leading to more efficient model training.

Disadvantages:

- Loss of Label-Specific Information: By combining all labels into a single sample, the model may not effectively capture the nuanced relationships between the sentence and individual labels, potentially leading to lower classification accuracy for specific labels.
- Complex Relationship Representation: The model may struggle to learn complex relationships between the sentence and multiple labels within a single sample, potentially impacting its ability to accurately classify the input.
- Limited Label-Specific Training: The model may not receive sufficient training instances for each label, which could affect its ability to differentiate between different labels during classification.

I hope this helps you in evaluating the best approach for your project. If you have further questions or need additional insights, feel free to ask!